# Serve a React .net core template from subdomain

Tags: reactjs, .net, iis

I'm trying to serve a .net core (5.03) web app with the [React template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/react?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) from a subdomain, meaning it should serve the static assets from `https://someServer/someSite` and not from `https://someServer`, like the Web Server (IIS10) is doing right now after being pointed to the directory.

It serves the index.html file from the right place, But tries to get the other assets and calls from the main domain.

I tried to directly edit the `<base>` element, but to no use.

How do I configure what path should I serve from without ejecting the CRA and directly editing the webpack.config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you have to change %APP_PATH% env var in the CRA, or add an `homePage` property in your package.json (inside the ClientApp).
The settings in Startup.cs are already relative to the DLL path.